# How to generate Test Overview Report in Tessy using Python?

Tags: python, windows, automation, pywinauto

I need to generate Test Overview Report from Tessy using Python.

I tried using the **pywinauto **package.

the idea was to perform click operations where is needed in order to execute the specific test case and then to generate a report. The code is below.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

tessy = Application(backend='win32').start(r"C:\d\tools\tessy\TESSY_3_2_16\TESSY_3.2\bin\TESSY.exe").connect(title='TESSY | Project: b_800_sut_trunk', timeout=400)

tessy.TESSYProjectB800SutTrunk.print_control_identifiers()
```

print_control_identifiers should print all opctions like File Menu and its options and so on, but it doesn't. It prints something, but I can't find any matches with the actual interface options and what it prints.

If there is an easy way without using this package, I am also interested in it.

Comment: Maybe Tessy has the command line option to do it? What `TESSY.exe /?` prints/shows when run in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Maybe there is a separate executable for command line. Quote from the docs: "A command line executable provides all commands of the API for usage within DOS batch files.". If you figure out the right commands, they could be executed by standard Python module `subprocess`, for example, by `subprocess.check_output("some.exe --some-option some-value", shell=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few months later, but hope this might help.
Tessy comes with a command line tool, in Razorcat/Tessy_X.Y/bin called tessycmd.exe (the connection with an instance of Tessy.exe is made with TESSYD.exe, in the same folder, the instance can be with or without GUI).

Now, you need to actually create for the first time a batch operation, which executes the tests (optional, so you have the latest results) and creates the reports: overview, detailed, requirements and planned (last 2 I'm not really sure).

The batch operation menu inside Tessy GUI, is the engines next to the reports. There you can select which data will be stored in each report and the execution parameters. It is needed to save that batch operation once we configure the execution and reports, and then, call it with one of the options of the CLI.

With it, you can select a previously saved batch operation (I don't remember if one can be created just with the CLI, but I think that not), execute and generate the report.

More details are in the User Manual of Tessy under the Help menu.

Lastly: As far as I remember, Tessy.exe is an Eclipse based application, which actually calls ti.exe, te.exe tk.exe and ttk.exe or something like that in order to generate a set of perspectives and views. That might explain why you cannot see the menus of the GUI.
If it really needs to be done in python, making the calls to the CLI would be the only option I can think right now.

Also check the UNDOCUMENTED script _tessy_shell_startup_script in order to see a real implementation of the cli for new projects mainly.